# Linq Sql Query result is different from the SQL query run in the database

Tags: c#, sql, linq

When I run the query in C# code using Linq the result returned is different from the sql query run in sql server

SQL query

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [Teamid]
  ,[TeamName]
  ,[TemplateId]
  ,[TemplateName]
 FROM [MPFT_SendIT].[dbo].[VMTemplate]
 where
 Teamid=1
```

Result

[image]

SQL Query of the VMTemplate View

```
     SELECT        dbo.Team.Id AS Teamid, dbo.Team.TeamName, 
          dbo.MessageTemplate.Id AS TemplateId, 
            dbo.MessageTemplate.TemplateName
         FROM        dbo.Team INNER JOIN
                     dbo.TemplateLookup ON dbo.Team.Id = 
                    dbo.TemplateLookup.TeamId INNER JOIN
                    dbo.MessageTemplate ON dbo.TemplateLookup.TemplateId = 
                    dbo.MessageTemplate.Id
                     where
                     TeamId= 1
```

Result
[image]

Linq SQL

```
 var teamid = _db.TeamLookups.Where(i => i.UserId == 20).Select(x => 
  x.TeamId).ToList(); // teamid return value is 1

 ViewBag.messageTemplate = _db.VMTemplates.Where(i => 
 teamid.Contains(i.Teamid));
```

Linq query only returns one record line 1 of the sql query instead of 2 records as expected. Any help on how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Have you verified _for sure_ that the `SSMS` query and the `Linq` query are selecting from the same database?

Comment: Why is SQL using : "Teamid=1" while linq is using "i.UserId == 20"?

Comment: @jdweng I am using userid = 20 in teamlookup table to get the Teamid and I use that TeamId in second query to display the data in VMTemplate. I verified the both query are run from the same database

Comment: Have you made any changes to the database after you built the `Linq` model?

Comment: No I have not change the database

Comment: Ca you run exactly same query in SSMS and get same results?  Right now you are not comparing APPLES with APPLES, instead you are comparing APPLES with ORANGES.

Comment: @jdweng Edit my code with sql query on the VWTemplate

Comment: Suppose you team has two player.  The SQL will return the results for both team members while linq is returning results for only one team member.

Comment: @jdweng you are right. that  is the issue I am having

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) would prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

Why `Contains()`? You should use equality operator rather

```
_db.VMTemplates.Where(i => teamid == i.Teamid).ToList();
```

Per your comment, then your Linq expression should work just fine. Add a `ToList()` to it

```
ViewBag.messageTemplate = _db.VMTemplates.Where(i => 
 teamid.Contains(i.Teamid)).ToList();
```

Comment: I am using contain because the  var teamid = _db.TeamLookups.Where(i => i.UserId == 20).Select(x => 
  x.TeamId).ToList() can return more than one value

Comment: @EricMbiada so you want all the teamids or only teamid=1?

Comment: I want all the result from VMTemplates where i.Teamid = teamid  I use  teamid= 1 in this case because I did not want to return many record

Comment: @EricMbiada, how do you consume `ViewBag.messageTemplate` ?

Comment: @akos.pinter I am passing the result of the viewbag to a dropdown Html.DropDownList("MessageTemplate", new SelectList(ViewBag.messageTemplate, "TemplateId", "TemplateName"),
                         "Select a Message Template")